# Android Hangman game - User input

Tags: java, android

I am currently creating a Hangman android application and I am having trouble registering inputted letters and updating the game.  I input a letter with the onscreen keyboard into the EditText created, and nothing happens.

Below is the code I am using:

```
// Setting up user input
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputguess);
    input.setFocusable(true);
    input.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    //Getting user input
    input.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            String temp;
            String newLetter;

            newLetter = input.getText().toString();

            temp = (String)enteredText.getText();
            if (temp.indexOf(newLetter.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)) >= 0) {
                input.setText("");
                return true;
            }

            input.setText(""); // clearing input

            entered += newLetter.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH); // adding inputted letter to the entered string

            enteredText.setText(temp + newLetter.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
            word.setText(hideString(text, newLetter.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)));
```

The XML code of my EditText is the following:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputguess"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/guessedwords"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/guessletter"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLength="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone">
</EditText>
```

After researching, the only reason I can think of is the type of listener being used, but I am not entirely sure.  Any help would be greatly appreciated (Let me know if I should add more of my code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the OnKeyListener only works with hardware keyboards. To make use of the software (onscreen) keyboard, you must add a TextWatcher

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { ... })
```